# How do I send an email using awk to a list of email addresses in a text file?

Tags: linux, email, shell, variables, awk

If I have a text file with a list of email addresses, how can I go through the list and send an email to each of those email addresses with a text file as the message.
I.e. I want to take in an email as a variable so I can execute this command:

```
mail -s "Welcome" email@address.com < welcome.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

for example you have a `mails_addresses.txt` file with one address per line like that:

```
email1@mail.com
email2@mail.com
email3@mail.com
```

In case you have another complex structure which you need to parse with for example `awk` you should to show it us.

So you need just to write a loop which will read it and send it to `mail` command:

```
while read MAIL
do
    mail -s "Welcome" "$MAIL" < welcome.txt
done < mails_addresses.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this even without `awk`:

```
cat users-list | while read addr
do
mail -s "Welcome" "$addr" < welcome.txt
done
```

Comment: You could even do it without `cat`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: yes I know, but it does not matter :)